# PHP can't connect to MySQL after changing datadir

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, my.cnf

I have changed my MySQL datadir and socket location in my `/etc/my.cnf` as follows:

```
[mysqld]
#--default datadir
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#--new datadir
datadir=/data/lib/mysql

#--default socket
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#--new socket
socket=/data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# slow log
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysqld-slow.log
long-query-time=1


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
#--default socket
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#--new socket
socket=/data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

After writing my my.cnf as above, I restarted my mysqld with `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` .

I am able to connect to my MySQL via my terminal using `mysql -uroot -ppassword`, and my data coorectly exists, so there is no problem there.

But when I try to connect to MySQL in a simple index.php as follows:

```
<?
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', TRUE);
echo $link;
?>
```

I get the error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /var/ww/html/index.php on line 3
```

I can't figure out why my PHP is trying to look for `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` , when I have obviously changed it to `/data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

I am running a normal Apache v2.2.22 loading a normal `php5_module` .

I restarted my apache with both `restart` and `graceful`.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Which php mysql extension are you using?  `mysql`, `mysqli` or `pdo_mysql`?

Comment: I am using the plain old `mysql`. And it turns out that I had to specify my socket either in `mysql_connect()` or in `/etc/php.in` . Happily solved, thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally changed in your `php.ini` configuration file.

Depending on the php mysql extension you're using, the setting is a bit different.  If you don't set those properties, your mysql extension will use the default that has been configured at compile time, which is more than probably `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Once the property relative to the extension you're using is correctly set, there is no need to change any of your PHP code.

### pdo_mysql

If you're using the `pdo_mysql` extension to connect to your MySQL server, the configuration to look for is:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

### mysql

If you're using the `mysql` extension, configure the following:

```
mysql.default_socket = /data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

### mysqli

For the `mysqli`extension, look at:

```
mysqli.default_socket = /data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Been some time since I last messed with php but you can try

```
mysql_connect('localhost:/data/lib/mysql/mysql.sock', ........)
```

edit: check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This worked, but the real answer I wanted (which I just found out) was to set `mysql.default_socket` in `/etc/php.ini` .  Your advice helped me find this problem, thank you!

Comment: @ashiina You may also post your solution as an answer. Self-answer is encouraged, even rewarded, on SE.

Comment: @jscott was going to, but someone else has posted a clean answer so I marked his as the answer. Thanks for the tip!